# Does an SSL certificate have to cover the server hostnames returned by an SRV lookup on the domain?

Tags: tls, xmpp

I have XMPP service running on the domain `xmpp.mydomain.com`.

The XMPP service runs on two back-end servers, `im1.mydomain.com` and `im2.mydomain.com`. Clients find out about these servers by an `SRV` DNS lookup on the XMPP address:

```
c:\> nslookup -type=SRV _xmpp-client._tcp.xmpp.mydomain.com
_xmpp-client._tcp.xmpp.mydomain.com    SRV service location:
      priority       = 1
      weight         = 1
      port           = 5222
      svr hostname   = im1.mydomain.com
_xmpp-client._tcp.xmpp.mydomain.com    SRV service location:
      priority       = 1
      weight         = 1
      port           = 5222
      svr hostname   = im2.mydomain.com
im1.mydomain.com     internet address = x.y.z.1
im2.mydomain.com     internet address = x.y.z.2
```

I have an SSL certificate for the XMPP domain `xmpp.mydomain.com`.

However, when trying to connect to XMPP from an Android client, I get the following error: `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Hostname did not match identities: [xmpp.myserver.com]`

Is it correct to have the certificate just cover the parent XMPP domain (`xmpp.mydomain.com`)? Or should it cover the hostnames of the servers behind that domain (`im1.mydomain.com` and `im2.mydomain.com`)?